# Mixed operators in JSX

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I'd like to use mixed operators in JSX, for example:

```
{datas && datas.map(function(data,i){ return <MyComponent key={i} />}) || []}
```

While this technically works, ES lint warns of 'no-mixed-operators'. Is this a safe pattern to use in JSX?

Comment: Just turn off the lint rule? --> http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-mixed-operators#when-not-to-use-it

Comment: I realize I could do that. But I would like to know if using mixed use operators in JSX is a bad pattern and should be avoided.

Comment: Of course you can use mixed operators; it's valid JavaScript. The lint complaint just wants you to properly parenthesize them.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

From [the ESLint documentation](http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-mixed-operators):

### Disallow mixes of different operators (no-mixed-operators)

Enclosing complex expressions by parentheses clarifies the developer’s intention, which **makes the code more readable**. This rule warns when different operators are used consecutively without parentheses in an expression.

```
var foo = a && b || c || d;    /*BAD: Unexpected mix of '&&' and '||'.*/
var foo = (a && b) || c || d;  /*GOOD*/
var foo = a && (b || c || d);  /*GOOD*/
```

If you don’t want to be notified about mixed operators, then it’s safe to disable this rule.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Right, I didn't think this would apply JSX but if I simply do:

`{(datas && datas.map(function(data,i){ return <MyComponent key={i} />})) || []}`

it works.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can just Wrap in the parenthesis like this. It not going to show that warning.

`{datas && (datas.map(function(data,i){ return <MyComponent key={i} />}) || [])}`

It worked for me.